# How to install Java in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, dockerfile

I tried to install java in dockerfile with reference image `centos:latest` but getting an error:

```
Step 1/11 : FROM centos:latest
 ---> 5d0da3dc9764
Step 2/11 : RUN yum -y update
 ---> Running in 597c6b6cf3f4
CentOS Linux 8 - AppStream                      963  B/s |  38  B     00:00
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'appstream': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: No URLs in mirrorlist
The command '/bin/sh -c yum -y update' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to just use an image that is based of OpenJDK?

Comment: It's recommended to use the OpenJDK based image. But if you still want to use centos as the base image, then please check [this](https://www.tecmint.com/error-failed-to-download-metadata-for-repo-appstream/) for fixing the issue. As per the blog, add the `sed` commands in the `RUN` step before `yum -y update`